# Dashed subpath in solid path

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw a single path with several segments, but one segment should have a different style than the others:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);
\begin{scope}[yshift=1.3cm]
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw [dotted] (1,0) -- +(1,0);
\draw (2,0) -| +(1,1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(1,0) -| +(1,1);  % draw the middle
                                % segment dotted?
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I draw the top line, using only a single \draw - command? As you see, when using the 3-step approach I have to take care of the coordinates on my own, and I want tikz to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only possible way of achieving that is with decorations. Even though you can use coordinates so you don't need to keep track of the actual aboslute coordinates.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
    dotted anywhere/.style={
        decoration={
            markings,
            mark=between positions 0 and 1
                 step 5\pgflinewidth
                 with {\fill circle[radius=.5\pgflinewidth];}
        }
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (-1,-1) rectangle (4,3);
\begin{scope}[yshift=1.3cm]
\draw (0,0) -- +(1,0) coordinate (tmp);
% The tmp coordinate is used to continue the drawing on the next path specification
\draw [dotted] (tmp) -- +(1,0) coordinate (tmp);
\draw (tmp) -| +(1,1);
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}
\draw (0,0) -- ++(1,0) decorate[dotted anywhere]{-- ++(1,0)} -| +(1,1);  % draw the middle
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A detail: normal tikz `dotted` style is not actually "dotted", the dots are actually squares. I made the above MWE so the dots are actually circles, but this can be changed, of course.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your post! Though it works, its kinda unflexible, I'd need to define a new decoration style for each line style (e.g. if I want dashed and dotted lines). Isn't there some general syntax that can apply some style to only parts of a path?

Comment: Yeah well, what I proposed is as unflexible as tikz itself, only the styles you'll have to define yourself come out of the box from tikz. About the general syntax, no, there isn't. If you try and understand a bit more how Ti*k*Z work out the path construction you see how what you ask is actually *very* complicated.

Comment: If I were you, I would use the coordinates way, I don't see why that should be a problem. Decorations are more time consuming, so if your drawing is heavy then compilation time may become an issue.

Comment: Thanks for the info, then I might go with the coordinate way, though it's not as terse as it could be (optimally).